# how to scroll down and up by mouse wheel only in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am used horizontal scroll bar in `jqgrid` with set `scroll:true`.

It work fine but I want to scroll up and down by mouse wheel not by using this scroll bar.

Is it possible disabled or lock scroll bar but allow scrolling by mouse wheel only?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you need to use `scroll:1` instead of `scroll:true`, Which will not disable scroll bar, but it will solve your issue.